# Interpolation of a 2D segment using its projection

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, projective-geometry

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

The blue segment is projected on the orange projection screen from a specific point of view. The projection is shown at the bottom of the image. About the blue segment is known the following: the orthogonal distance between the point of view and each of the segment's edges, `d1` and `d2`.

Now we select a point on the projected segment, such that it splits the projected segment into 2 segments of length `p1` and `p2`.

### Is there a way, with that information, to calculate the orthogonal distance `d` from the point of view to the actual point represented by the point on the projected segment?

If so, how? If not, what info would be required?

---

Notes:

The complexity comes from the fact that the proportions of the projected segment do no respect the proportions of the original segment (notice how the original segment is roughly split in half, while the projected segment is not split in equal halves, i.e. `p1` is not equal to `p2`).

Since the segment is straight, I wonder if there is a formula that would give the ratio on the segment based on the ratio on the projected segment. I've done some empirical tests to find the `p1/(p1+p2)` ratio that represents the exact middle of the original segment. `x1` and `x2` are the other coordinate of the left and right segment, respectively.

| x1 | d1 | x2 | d2 | ratio | p1/(p1+p2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.5 | 1 | 0.5 | 2 | 0.5 | 2/3 |
| -0.5 | 1 | 0.5 | 3 | 0.5 | 6/8 |
| -0.5 | 1 | 0.5 | 4 | 0.5 | 8/10 |

Comment: The concept of cross-ratio may be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Projection]

Here is the recipe, which would help you to find an expression for $d$ in terms of $d_1$, $d_2$, $p_1$, and $p_2$. Throughout this exercise, you will be using properties of a pair of similar triangles stated in Theorem Euclid VI. 4.

First, as shown in the diagram, let the orthogonal distance between the orange screen and the point of view be $d_0$. You do not need to worry about its length, because it will be used only to facilitate the derivation and will not appear in the final expression.

Two right-angled triangles $CMD$ and $CLA$ are similar. Apply the mentioned theorem to them to obtain an expression for $a$ in terms of $p_1$, $d_0$, and $d_1$.

Similarly, the pair of right-angled triangles $JMC$ and $BLC$ are also similar. Apply the mentioned theorem to them to obtain an expression for $b$ in terms of $p_2$, $d_0$, and $d_1$.

Two right-angled triangles $JKE$ and $JMC$ are similar. Apply the mentioned theorem to them to obtain an expression for $c$ in terms of $p_2$, $d_0$, $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Use the three formulae derived above to express $e$ in terms of $p_1$, $p_2$, $d_0$, $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Two right-angled triangles $DKE$ and $DMN$ are similar. Apply the mentioned theorem to them to obtain an expression for $f$ in terms of $p_1$, $p_2$, $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Finally, use the formula derived last, to obtain the sought expression for $d$ in terms of $p_1$, $p_2$, $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Comment: Interesting approach. But this assumes that the point L (and therefore the point N) are placed such that the triangle CMD is right-angled, does it not?

Comment: I suppose that the point C can be placed to guarantee right-angled triangles, but that voids the use of p1 and p2.

Comment: The answer to your question is “Yes, the points $L$ and $N$ are placed such that the $\triangle CMD$ is right-angled”. But I could not follow what you have stated in your second comment. Therefore, we have two options. The first one is to delete our answer, if you think it is not correct. The second option is to check the validity of the formulae derived using the method described in our answer by plugging some appropriate numerical values for $p_1$, $p_2$, $d_1$ and $d_2$. Assuming that you have not yet derived the formulae for $d$ and $\dfrac{DN}{NE}$, I give ours in the next comment.

Comment: $$d=\dfrac{d_1d_2\left(p_1+p_2\right)}{d_1p_1+d_2p_2}\qquad\qquad\qquad \dfrac{DN}{NE}=\dfrac{d_1p_1}{d_2p_2}$$
If you check the results of the second equation with the values given in your table, you can see that they are agreeing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The formulae is indeed correct, but I wanted to be certain. For example I had issues with cases where part of the segment DE is behind the point C. In the end the equation holds true in all cases except when the segment coincides with the projection axis (there exists an infinity of answer then) or when d=0 (point at which the segment passes behind the point C, p1 and p2 will be infinite).